# NSClassFromString will not allow me to set a delegate

Tags: uiviewcontroller, delegates

I use NSClassFromString to alloc viewcontrollers. But this will not let me set a delegate to self. Is it possible?

```
nibString = @"ViewControllerName";
Class viewControllerClass = NSClassFromString( nibString );
loadedVC = (UIViewController*) [[viewControllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:nibString bundle:nil];
[loadedVC setDelegate:self];
```

The last line reports No visible@interface for "UIViewController" declares the selector 'setDelegate'

I am sure if I allocate the vc via property it will work but I use this method for convenience - although maybe I should stop if I can give set it's delegate.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have declared `loadedVC` like this:

```
UIViewController *loadedVC;
```

The compiler will only let you send it messages that it knows are part of `UIViewController`'s `@interface`.  This is a good thing.  It prevents lots of runtime errors.  But sometimes you know better than the compiler, and you want to turn off the `@interface` check.

When you try to send a message to a value of type `id`, the compiler doesn't check the message, because `id` is a generic type that has no `@interface`.  So cast `loadedVC` to `id`:

```
[(id)loadedVC setDelegate:self];
```

Note that if `loadedVC` does not have (or inherit) a `setDelegate:` method, you will get a run-time error.  If you want to check for the method first, try this:

```
if ([loadedVC respondsToSelector:@selector(setDelegate:)]) {
    [(id)loadedVC setDelegate:self];
}
```

Another way you can do it is by creating a protocol containing a `setDelegate:` method:

```
@protocol HasDelegate
- (void)setDelegate:(id)delegate;
@end
```

Then you can declare `loadedVC` like this to tell the compiler that it conforms to the protocol:

```
UIViewController<HasDelegate> *loadedVC;
```

Now the compiler won't complain when you try to send `setDelegate:` to `loadedVC` (even without a cast).  But you will still get a runtime error if `loadedVC` doesn't actually have a `setDelegate:` method.

Answer (score 1):

The UIViewControler class does not have a delegate property.  Normally you set the view controller as the delegate of the view, so setDelegate would be called on the view, not the controller.

If you have a view controller subclass that does support a delegate, it will not be visible to the compiler since your loadedVC reference has been cast to the UIViewControler.  If this is the problem, there are several solutions.

1) You can cast to the class used, or the first superclass that implements a delegate.

2) You can use a formal or informal protocol.

3) You can call respondsToSelector:, followed by performSelector:withObject:

etc.